# swagger typescript/angular2 client

Tags: angular, typescript

I've generated my client using typescript2/angular2 language using [swagger codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) code generator.

I'm not able to figure out what's been generated and how to use the artifacts.

As far I've been able to figure out, headers are not included on request in `create` method (`user` and `passwd` parameters). Otherwise, I don't understand how requests are made. I've set a breakpoint inside `map` method callback and it's never reached.

You can take a look on [UsersApi.ts](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/062aa6932596fbbce355689e2e660bb6).

Comment: As of Feb 2017, as best as I can tell, nobody has done any work to document how to use the generated Angular 2 client. Swagger-codegen documentation says that you should refer to the README included with the downloaded client. There is no README file, so I'm guessing it's a simple case of nobody wanting to write the documentation (hilariously ironic, considering the topic - The software that helps automate documentation has no documentation itself).

Comment: If you were using swagger 2.2.2 this was bugged, the newer 2.2.3 version considerably changes the generated code. I'd try that before continuing, although you probably have by now.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a swagger codegen generated client (typescript/ng2) in my current project.

First i take the generated output and place it into my project.  You can automate this or not.  Depending on how much your api is expected to change.  I put mine into 'app/core/api' and this includes the api folder and the model folder and a half dozen or so other files.  and a .swagger-codegen folder too (though I am not 100% sure this is needed).

1. Create a service to wrap your use of the generated api, thus decoupling your components from it (in case it changes).  So for your example I would create my own user.service.ts to be consumed by my components.
2. In your UserService class you need to import the public api from the generated code.  this is usually in api/index.ts or just:
   import * as client from 'app/core/api';
   this is simpler when you only have a single api.  if you have multiple ones they are exported as an array called APIS from api/api.ts/
3. To use the api you don't need to create headers or params or any of that.  the generated service has methods that should take the values that the call needs and it handles making the json request and response objects.  Looking through the models folder and the service ts itself should make this a little clearer.  but for your example you have only 2 methods.  create and exists.  in your UserService you create a method called CreateUser or whatever you like and inside it you call the api method create.  pass it the username string and the password string.  that is it.  it will return an observable of whatever the api call returns (it converts the json response to a typescript object (defined in the models directory in the api generated code).
4. For your example it doesn't seem to be using custom objects. the create method just returns Observable<{}>.  So you can make a call to it and map the response to your own User class instance and use that to bind to your view template.  Again staying decoupled from the api details.

Hope this helps.  I would be happy to answer more specific questions.